# Request multiple random number at once on chainlink VRF

Tags: solidity, chainlink, mainnet

Would it be possible to require more than one random number on the chainlink VRF with only one call to requestRandomness or any other function ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get multiple random numbers from a single VRF response, you should create an array where the randomValue is your original returned VRF number and n is the desired number of random numbers.

```
function expand(uint256 randomValue, uint256 n) public pure returns (uint256[] memory expandedValues) {
    expandedValues = new uint256[](n);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        expandedValues[i] = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(randomValue, i)));
    }
    return expandedValues;
}
```

This code snippet takes the initial random value, puts it inside a for loop, combines it with an incrementing number by [ABI encoding](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts/1171) the random number and incremented number, hashes that encoding using Keccak256, and finally type casts the hash to a type `uint` to be used as that now expanded random number. The loop then continues for as many random numbers needed, which were set with the `n` parameter of the function.

Reference: [VRF Best Practices](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/#getting-multiple-random-numbers)