# How to call any smart contract functions without getting their ABI?

Tags: contract-invocation, web3.py, abi

I make python bots for smart contracts, but I'm not too much of an expert.

What I usually do is download the ABI from the block explorers. However, what if I want to call a function from any random contract address without having its ABI?

*I want to make a way to generate the ABI for the function* - where I know what's the name of the function, and what would be the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I suggest you to first take a look at [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/119506/86679) answer to get familiar with the ABI concept.
- After reading that, you could use [etherscan's api](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/contracts) to do the job.

Hope this helps.