# How to create custom gnosis transactions?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Using the `safe-core-sdk`, I'm trying to make a custom transaction. Based on the doc, I need to make a dataPartial, sign it, then execute it.
Question is.. how do I go about crafting the `data` field for this object?

```
            const safeTransactionData: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
                to: '',
                value: '0',
                data: '0x'.  <--- this
            };
    
            const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({
                safeTransactionData
            });
```

Could anyone point me to the right resource?

Comment: I think you can leave it as 0x if your Safe is not calling a contract. If it is, then you would [use the ABI of the contract you're calling](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the data object using ethersjs library like below:

```
        const contractInterface = new utils.Interface(Abi);
        const data = contractInterface.encodeFunctionData('transfer', [
            address,
            utils.parseUnits('1')
        ]);
```