# How do I find out the solidity compiler version I am using?

Tags: solidity, mist, solc

Specifically, while using **Mist**. When I create a contract via the Mist GUI, I want to then be able to verify the source code over at Etherscan.  However, Etherscan requires that you provide the compiler version and whether or not optimizations were enabled.

- How can I find the version of the compiler for the version of Mist that I have?
- Are optimizations always enabled or always disabled?
- Does TEST-NET vs Main net make a difference?

Note: I am looking for an answer to how to find the compiler version, not the current Mist compiler version (which will change making the answer only transient).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Mist / Ethereum Wallet** now has a built-in compiler that is not very well documented beyond screenshots in the tutorials in order to create, compile, and deploy contracts. However, the version of Mist's compiler and whether or not it is optimized is...hard to figure out.

- [Go to the Mist releases page.](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/)
- Click on the release you are using. [ie: 0.5.2](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.5.2)
- Click "CODE" at the top. [example link](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/tree/0.5.2)
- Click `package.json'. [example link](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/0.5.2/package.json)
- Look for `"solc": "^0.X.X-X",`. That is the version. So for Mist 0.5.2, the solc version is 0.2.1-1.

However, this does NOT necessarily solve your problem with getting verified on EtherScan. I cannot get the token code to match either, no matter what I tried (and I tried a lot). See the bottom of this comment if you want to dive in with me.

- [Alex van de Sande asks EtherScan while their verify isn't working. No response.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4bj48x/etherchain_i_cant_use_your_verify_contract/)

---

**If getting verified on EtherScan is important to you**, then write your Solidity code wherever but compile it using Browser Solidity here: http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/

Then use that bytecode to deploy. I have not tested it but the code it spits out for the sample token contract matches what EtherScan spits out. I assume that EtherScan is using that same browser-based compiler to check and verify contracts.

---

If you are using **Mix IDE / Solidity**, you can view the Solidity version by going (in the Mix IDE) to File/Mix/Help - > About.

---

If you are using **solc / Solidity (command line interface)** you can use the command [`web3.eth.compile`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcompilesolidity) which will then spit out something like:

```
contract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test
{
  code: '605280600c6000396000f3006000357c010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000090048063c6888fa114602e57005b60376004356041565b8060005260206000f35b6000600782029050604d565b91905056',
  info: {
    language: 'Solidity',
    languageVersion: '0',
    compilerVersion: '0.9.13',
    abiDefinition: [{
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{
        name: 'a',
        type: 'uint256'
      } ],
      name: 'multiply',
      outputs: [{
        name: 'd',
        type: 'uint256'
      } ],
      type: 'function'
    } ],
    userDoc: {
      methods: {
      }
    },
    developerDoc: {
      methods: {
      }
    },
    source: 'contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }'
  }
}
```

This will compile your code and give you information like compiler version, etc.

[More Information](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions)

---

**Optimization** is a choice you can make. Via solc, you use the `--optimize` flag. You can read more about this magical optimization property here:
[How does the solidity optimizer work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/698/how-does-the-solidity-optimizer-work). I think Mist is optimizing based on the fact that I had a 73% similarity when I chose "not optimized" on EtherScan and a 93% similarity when I chose optimized.

---

**Contract Testing:**

I have created the exact contract https://www.ethereum.org/token#the-code with no change whatsoever to the code using Mist v 0.5.2.

The contract code that Etherscan.io received / Mist sent was:

```
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
```

You can see this on EtherScan, or you can get it in Ethereum Wallet by opening the console and running `TokenContract.eth.getCode('YOUR_ADDRESS_HERE_NO_0x_AT_BEGINNING');` Both Mist and EtherScan spit out the same code.

I attempted to verify maybe 20 different versions, with and without optimization, using [Browser Solidity](http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/) and never once is that code as short or Etherscan.io has it, nor does it start with 0x.....

Here is an example of what Browser Solidity & EtherScan give me using 0.2.1-3ad5e821 w/ optimization:

```
606060405260405161092b38038061092b83398101604052805160805160a05160c05160e05193949283019391929081019101600160a060020a03331660009081526005602090815260408220879055600487905581548651838052601f6002600019600185161561010002019093169290920482018390047f290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e56390810193919290918901908390106100d457805160ff19168380011785555b506101049291505b8082111561015d57600081556001016100c0565b828001600101855582156100b8579182015b828111156100b85782518260005055916020019190600101906100e6565b50508160016000509080519060200190828054600181600116156101000203166002900490600052602060002090601f016020900481019282601f1061016157805160ff19168380011785555b506101919291506100c0565b5090565b82800160010185558215610151579182015b82811115610151578251826000505591602001919060010190610173565b50506003805460ff19168417905560028054825160008390527f405787fa12a823e0f2b7631cc41b3ba8828b3321ca811111fa75cd3aa3bb5ace602060018416156101000260001901909316849004601f90810184900482019386019083901061020e57805160ff19168380011785555b5061023e9291506100c0565b82800160010185558215610202579182015b82811115610202578251826000505591602001919060010190610220565b505050505050506106d8806102536000396000f36060604052361561008d5760e060020a600035046306fdde03811461009557806318160ddd146100f257806323b872dd146100fb578063313ce5671461012d57806354fd4d501461013957806370a082311461019357806395d89b41146101ab578063a9059cbb14610207578063cae9ca5114610236578063dc3080f214610398578063dd62ed3e146103bd575b6103e2610002565b6103e460008054602060026001831615610100026000190190921691909104601f810182900490910260809081016040526060828152929190828280156104995780601f1061046e57610100808354040283529160200191610499565b61045260045481565b610452600435602435604435600160a060020a0383166000908152600560205260408120548290101561057057610002565b61046460035460ff1681565b6103e460028054602060018216156101000260001901909116829004601f810182900490910260809081016040526060828152929190828280156104995780601f1061046e57610100808354040283529160200191610499565b61045260043560056020526000908152604090205481565b6103e4600180546020600282841615610100026000190190921691909104601f810182900490910260809081016040526060828152929190828280156104995780601f1061046e57610100808354040283529160200191610499565b6103e2600435602435600160a060020a033316600090815260056020526040902054819010156104a157610002565b60806020604435600481810135601f810184900490930284016040526060838152610452948235946024803595606494939101919081908382808284375094965050505050505060006000836006600050600033600160a060020a03168152602001908152602001600020600050600087600160a060020a031681526020019081526020016000206000508190555084905080600160a060020a0316638f4ffcb1338630876040518560e060020a0281526004018085600160a060020a0316815260200184815260200183600160a060020a03168152602001806020018281038252838181518152602001915080519060200190808383829060006004602084601f0104600f02600301f150905090810190601f16801561036b5780820380516001836020036101000a031916815260200191505b50955050505050506000604051808303816000876161da5a03f11561000257506001979650505050505050565b6007602090815260043560009081526040808220909252602435815220546104529081565b6006602090815260043560009081526040808220909252602435815220546104529081565b005b60405180806020018281038252838181518152602001915080519060200190808383829060006004602084601f0104600f02600301f150905090810190601f1680156104445780820380516001836020036101000a031916815260200191505b509250505060405180910390f35b60408051918252519081900360200190f35b6060908152602090f35b820191906000526020600020905b81548152906001019060200180831161047c57829003601f168201915b505050505081565b600160a060020a0382166000908152604090205480820110156104c357610002565b806005600050600033600160a060020a03168152602001908152602001600020600082828250540392505081905550806005600050600084600160a060020a0316815260200190815260200160002060008282825054019250508190555081600160a060020a031633600160a060020a03167fddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef836040518082815260200191505060405180910390a35050565b600160a060020a03831681526040812054808301101561058f57610002565b600160a060020a038085168083526006602090815260408085203394909416808652938252808520549285526007825280852093855292905290822054830111156105d957610002565b816005600050600086600160a060020a03168152602001908152602001600020600082828250540392505081905550816005600050600085600160a060020a03168152602001908152602001600020600082828250540192505081905550816007600050600086600160a060020a03168152602001908152602001600020600050600033600160a060020a0316815260200190815260200160002060008282825054019250508190555082600160a060020a031684600160a060020a03167fddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef846040518082815260200191505060405180910390a3506001939250505056
```

So....it still doesn't match what Mist supposedly sent and EtherScan received.

While doing research, I found that EtherChain may have better luck with verification. I, however, still could not get anything above ~93% similarity (using 2.1.1, optimized).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I am just using Mist GUI > Contracts > Deploy New Contract > Deploy

Comment: Ethereum Wallet > About Ethereum Wallet (Windows) just lists the Mist version (0.6.2 in this case).

Comment: I tried `web3.eth.compile.solidity` from the developer console, it just returns a `JavaScript` function.

Comment: `web3.eth.getCompilers()` returns `[""]`.  I was able to deploy a contract with Mist, which suggests that there is a compiler somewhere.  My Mist is backed by `geth` at the moment and when I used Mist to create the contract.

Comment: @MicahZoltu did you write this contract? Or did you just find the bytecode somewhere? Can you add exactly what you are putting into Mist in your question. Thank you.

Comment: I copied the contract source code from a tutorial online for how to create a new token.  https://www.ethereum.org/token#the-code

Comment: I'm having this same issue now. I want to verify a live contract but I can't find my compiler version and if optimization was on. The geth.compile.solidity command isn't found from the Mist wallet folder.

Comment: are you sure geth.compile.solidity is the command you meant to suggest? I double checked and my geth command line is working fine but that command does not seem to exist.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride sorry - its all `web3.eth.compile` now.

Comment: This is the response I get http://pastebin.com/rpxbkTjc no version number

Comment: So I found a `web3.eth.getCompilers` using the console in Mist, but can't get it to return anything. In other news, I just created a token. Stand by...

Comment: Hey guys --- updated the above answer with tons more information. My conclusion: EtherScan verification isn't worth this %&@$. Goodnight. ;)

Comment: @Tayvano thank you! This answer was a huge help I found the exact same thing as you. Once I followed your instructions and switched to etherchain everything worked.

Comment: npm-shrinkwrap.json contains locked version

Comment: `If getting verified on EtherScan is important to you` - that's the exact reason why I'm here...

Answer (score 4):

Right now there is no real easy way. I am trying to figure it out myself ;-)

When you are running a developer version in electron, you can always go to the folder running the mist code and type:

`node`

which then takes you to a node terminal where you can check your solidity version:

```
var solc = require('solc')
solc.version()

> '0.2.1-91a6b35f/.-Emscripten/clang/int linked to libethereum-'
```

Ideally our goal is to have mist broadcast the source code and compiler version on the network so services like etherchain and etherscan can verify it.

Last time I tried verifying the contract on the ethereum tip jar (which I deployed myself) I was only able to get to 97% similarity. I haven't had a chance to test it but I believe the difference is on parameters sent to the constructor function, as the changes only happen on the end of the file.