# Ethereum wallet version 0-7-5 - Solidity compiler version?

Tags: solidity

Is there a way to get the Solidity compiler version used by the official Ethereum wallet when deploying a contract to the blockchain?

Comment: Found the question asked previously here - http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/how-do-i-find-out-the-solidity-compiler-version-i-am-using