# How to update the Ethereum Wallet Solidity Compiler

Tags: solidity, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, compiler

I'm using the latest Ethereum Wallet version which is 0.9.0 and I want to update my latest Solidity compiler since it seems that the wallet is using this version

```
0.4.13+commit.0fb4cb1a.Emscripten.clang
```

I wanted to update the compiler in order to execute the Shareholders Association code in ethereum.org without error. The error I've been having is this:

```
Variable is declared as a storage pointer. Use an explicit "storage" keyword to silence this warning.
```

I've read a previous post about how to know the Solidity Compiler version which is this link:

[How do I find out the solidity compiler version I am using?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/how-do-i-find-out-the-solidity-compiler-version-i-am-using)

However, the answers are not necessarily giving instructions on how to update the compiler.

Comment: Im having the same issue, and I have the last release version, Using Ethereum Wallet 0.91.