# Difference Gas Report and Reality

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate, foundry

I work with Foundry (Forge, Anvil, Cast).

According to their [documentation](https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/gas-snapshots) one can run a gas estimation for the tests one has written.

I have a very simple test for which I wanted to have a gas estimate, because I could then infer how much gas this function call (I'm talking about (`withdraw`)) approx. uses.

```
function testWithdrawIsolated() public {
        vm.startPrank(whitelistedAddresses[0]); // <- withdraw can only called by owner, this is the owner
        cryptoDevs.withdraw();
    }
```

It reported `CryptoDevsTest:testWithdrawIsolated() (gas: 13113)`

So I assumed withdraw uses approx. less than 13k gas.

However, when I ran the `withdraw` function in remix with my browser wallet, 5 times out of 5 it ran with 30621 Gas.

**My Question**

Why is the gas amount so different?

Comment: Remix and Forge are two rather different development environments, so it is expected for there to be a few slight differences, but in your case the most likely explanation is that you haven't enabled the optimizer in Remix, whereas in Foundry you did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the solidity optimizer work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/698/how-does-the-solidity-optimizer-work)

Comment: okay I haven't thought about optimisation, fair point. But I deployed the contract with Foundry to Goerli and to Localhost, and in when I was working with Remix I just interacted with the contract deployed to Goerli (referenced the contract via the deployed address) and in both cases (localhost with anvil and goerli via remix) it used 30621. @PaulRazvanBerg

Comment: but for the testing contract it used only 13k