# Trustlessness and Provability in DApp design

Tags: contract-design, security, dapp-development

I am looking for suggestions or references on how to build proper **trustlessness** and **provability** into my DApps. These are DApp distinctives, but I find that thinking this through is like peeling back an onion.

What factors **must** be taken into account, and are there any factors that do not necessarily have to be addressed to be a credible DApp? Is provability accomplished just by the fact that the code is visible in the block chain using tools like ether.camp, or should a developer make more demonstrable provisions?

For example, I am contemplating a game contract that can be instantiated by human sponsors in the wild. Once launched, a new player of a given game instance would provide an entrance fee and compete for prizes. I presume the following must be clear:

- How funds are trustlessly held and disbursed by code.
- That game rules and play elements are contractually controlled.
- That all parameters a sponsor can configure are visible along with how they
  are set for a given game instance.

But how are things like the following ‘proven’ to be sufficiently ‘trustless’:

- That a ‘bad actor’ sponsor cannot exploit a game instance somehow,
  say exploiting aggregated player data that might not visible to
  players.
- That game physics/computations are true and unexploitable.
- That the base contract code is beyond manipulation by a sponsor or
  the original writer.

To summarize, what factors, principles, or references can anyone suggest for helping with good DApp design in the area of acceptable trustlessness and provability?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until more tools are developed, and tools and interfaces that are easy for most people to understand, here are some suggestions:

- provide an easy way for [verifying the deployed code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/195/42)
- provide well-written, abstracted, and documented code (the opposite of [underhanded coding](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4e5y30/live_example_of_underhanded_solidity_coding_on))
- provide clear and comprehensive tests for the code
- provide a version on testnet
- provide a development version that is easy for developers to run on their own and investigate
- pay for a reputable security audit
- leverage [existing tools](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3qfw0y/formal_verification_of_solidity_contracts_using)