# Is there a Solidity decompiler?

Tags: solidity, decompilers

Is there a decompiler that will convert Solidity byte code back into source code? I am wondering how to verify code of contracts that are published to the blockchain.

Comment: Please also take care to ask a single question :)  2nd question is answered [here](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/195/42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no decompiler to Solidity. This is in principle possible to
>   some degree, but for example variable names will be lost and great
>   effort will be necessary to make it look similar to the original
>   source code.
>
> Bytecode can be decompiled to opcodes, a service that is provided by
>   several blockchain explorers.
>
> Contracts on the blockchain should have their original source code
>   published if they are to be used by third parties.

Retrieved from: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html

Comment: This is no longer accurate, please refer to duplicate question link in comment on original question above.