# Truffle Bytecode Different from Etherscan Bytecode

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, solc

I am having difficulty verifying my contract code on Etherscan using the code generated by Truffle.

---

### Using Etherscan VerifyContract V1: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract

Truffle produced the bytecode: ([found here on Etherscan Rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x26dd2f3fcebdae819e20d07cc871bf0abbf72c4cbcdc87ad45608a534cbf2dee))

Etherscan's `Verify Contract Code` produced the `ContractByteCode`:

```
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
```

with `ContractABI` (not shown here)

---

### Using Etherscan VerifyContract V2: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract2

**Your Compiled Bytecode + Constructor Argument if any (what you provided):**

```
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
```

**ByteCode on the Blockchain (what we are looking for):**

```
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
```

---

On Etherscan I have selected the compiler `v0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52` and Optimzation `Enabled`.

I found the version of Truffle's compiler to be `0.4.17` from the file `node_modules/solc/package.json` from the line `"version": "0.4.17"`.

**Problem:**

On `verifyContract`, the bytecode produced by Truffle appears to be slightly longer than that produced by Etherscan.

On `verifyContract2` the bytecode produced by Truffle appears to be slightly shorter than that produced by Etherscan.

Has anyone encountered this problem and solved it?

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue with Embark. Bytecode is not matched. Did you get any solution?

Comment: You bytecode code is not only longer/shorter, but it is just different.  Most probably your compiler version does not match.  Could you show contract's source code?  What `solc --version` tells you?

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan and other services display the `runtime bytecode`, that is the active contract's real code.

When compiling with an IDE, Solidity or otherwise, by default the generated code is the "creation bytecode", simply called `bytecode`. That bytecode is executed once by a miner to create your contract, ie execution(bytecode)=>runtime_bytecode.

Additional details in this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7748/47677

Comment: How exactly does that answer the question?

Comment: You are correct, I think I misread / read too fast, not sure what happened here. Thanks for pointing it out.