# Difference between bytecode and runtime bytecode

Tags: bytecode

In Remix, clicking on "details" for a contract reveals the "bytecode" and "runtime bytecode". What is the difference?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/bytecode-on-block-chain-different-from-the-one-used-when-deploying

Comment: Note that Truffle and Hardhat renamed the "runtime bytecode" to "deployed bytecode".

Answer (score 14):

Runtime bytecode is what's actually stored at the contract address. It doesn't include the constructor function or initialization code (which the bytecode does).

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3pq08g/some_quick_things_about_verifying_contracts/cw8qn0d/