# Smart Contract byte code using web3

Tags: web3js, bytecode

How Could I pull out smart contract bytecode using web3 and contract address?

Answer (score 1):

Using Web3.js you can easily extract the bytecode for a contract at a certain address using the [`getCode()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getcode) function:

> [**getCode**](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getcode)
>
> ```
> web3.eth.getCode(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])
> ```

```
web3.eth.getCode("0xd5677cf67b5aa051bb40496e68ad359eb97cfbf8")
.then(console.log);
> "0x600160008035811a818181146012578301005b601b6001356025565b8060005260206000f25b600060078202905091905056"
```

Comment: I thought this will be it, but its not. This is getting current sc bytecode, I was looking for something to get bytecode so I can use it to deploy new sc

Comment: It's not that simple unfortunately: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/bytecode-on-block-chain-different-from-the-one-used-when-deploying