# Where is the contract bytecode stored when a contract creates a contract?

Tags: bytecode, internal-transactions

When a contract creates a contract, where's the new contract's bytecode stored?

For example:
This Maker contract was created by their deployment contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x448a5065aebb8e423f0896e6c5d525c040f59af3
here's the internal transaction: https://etherscan.io/txsInternal?block=4752011

Etherscan says `0x448a5065aebb8e423f0896e6c5d525c040f59af3` was created in transaction `0xa066bef4d74ad5433cc89ea21799d7df3e2f37ec0879f9ca74c419e861064fbf` and normally, when an external transaction creates a contract, that bytecode is in the blockchain in the `input`.

In this case, data was sent to the deployment (existing) contract to tell it to deploy a new contract, but the bytecode for the new contract is not in the blockchain data. Would the bytecode be in the event logs? or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an implementation detail where contract bytecode is stored: a Geth node can store it differently from a Parity node. What matters is that the APIs across all nodes are consistent.

[`web3.eth.getCode(someAddress)`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode) will give the bytecode of a contract at `someAddress`.

---

> normally, when an external transaction creates a contract, that bytecode is in the blockchain in the `input`.

Not exactly.  It may be a common misunderstanding that the `input` is the code of the created contract, but **actually the `input` is code that returns the contract code**.  See
[Bytecode on block chain different from the one used when deploying](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/bytecode-on-block-chain-different-from-the-one-used-when-deploying)

Comment: i'm working on extracting all data in an automated fashion, i think in order to use the web3.eth.getCode method to get the bytecode I need to be able to determine when an internal transaction creates a contract, as opposed to just calls a contract. like etherscan shows: https://etherscan.io/txsInternal?block=4752011. any idea how to determine this?

Comment: i didn't ask the question i wanted to correctly, but this does answer the question i asked :)

Answer (score 2):

The code of a contract is part of it's account state. Every account in ethereum has a state which consists of it's balance, code, storage, and nonce.

The tree consisting of the states of every individual accounts is known as the state tree (trie). Transactions can be seen as transitions between state tries. So when you send a transaction that causes a contract to deploy, that is seen as a modification to state, much as changing storage or balances would be.

As @eth pointed out, you can in general retrieve information about the state from a node via `eth.getX` where `X` is the type of information you want