# web3.eth.getCode doesn't return the data shown on etherscan

Tags: web3js, etherscan, bytecode

For example, let's take contract address 0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7.

Does anybody have an idea why the following two are totally different:

1. The string returned from `await web3.eth.getCode(0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7)`
2. The string under `Contract Creation Code` at
   https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code

I am using Web3.js v1.2.1.

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76334/what-is-the-difference-between-bytecode-init-code-deployed-bytecode-creation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because they are not the same thing.

When you execute the [`getCode(...)`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth.html#getcode) function, you get the deployed bytecode of a specific address, as the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth.html#getcode) says. The bytecode on the blockchain is the result of the execution of the compiled bytecode of your contract, which includes initialization code.

About the contract you provide, which is verified:

1. `await web3.eth.getCode(0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7)`

Returns the bytecode of the deployed contract.

2. Contract Creation Code

This is the `input` of the transaction that creates the contract, as you can see [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2f1c5c2b44f771e942a8506148e256f94f1a464babc938ae0690c6e34cd79190) in the `Input Data` field. This bytecode includes initialization code and will result in the bytecode deployed on the blockchain.

---

Let's see an example about a [non verified contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x004c8981FdDA3219d4F1319a50b2EfC9F52D36B3).

With: `web3.eth.getCode("0x004c8981FdDA3219d4F1319a50b2EfC9F52D36B3")`

What you will get is the bytecode of the contract on the blockchain:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x004c8981FdDA3219d4F1319a50b2EfC9F52D36B3#code

Which is not the same as the input of the transaction that creates the contract, which is the `contract creation code`.

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xea40ca2f6be3f146b7a4f80c97319e6658f5cc1118330f4b4bf76a7df10c6f0f

Probably here is explained better:

- [Where is the contract bytecode stored when a contract creates a
  contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69649/where-is-the-contract-bytecode-stored-when-a-contract-creates-a-contract?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Bytecode on block chain different from the one used when
  deploying](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/bytecode-on-block-chain-different-from-the-one-used-when-deploying)

Comment: The more hard case, when the contract created by another contract. 
For example: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfc6598e53dce60a8e70711226b710c72e0906152a5a8ec59f921d83e366cca96
I couldn't find get the input data by the API.