# How to get "Contract creation code" when it's not verified yet?

Tags: solidity, bytecode

Is there any possibility to get the "creation bytecode" of the contract when it's not yet verified?

I have a token smart contract: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xae78b6e1231e7a852af60047a2ab16a40cefafb3#code

It's not verified by the owner, and the current bytecode as I understand is the "Runtime Bytecode". Because I want to verify the source code of this deployed smart contract matches with
my local one.

Answer (score 0):

I think my approach is a bit odd. We should not compare the runtime bytecode which is still problematic, explained by [Bytecode on block chain different from the one used when deploying](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/bytecode-on-block-chain-different-from-the-one-used-when-deploying)

The proper way to do is to compare the compiled byte code with the input data of the tx. In local, we can just use `solc --bin --optimize <filename>.sol > op.bin` and compare the output with the `Input Data` .
[image]

Explained by [How can I verify that a contract on the blockchain matches the source code?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/195/how-can-i-verify-that-a-contract-on-the-blockchain-matches-the-source-code)
and [web3.eth.getCode doesn't return the data shown on etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77528/web3-eth-getcode-doesnt-return-the-data-shown-on-etherscan)

Comment: There is an issue to compare the exact bytecode: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-compile/issues/77